# Needing to backup software

Tags: backup, iso, dvd

I have some software that I bought from a now defunct product. Given that it isn't that popular, I don't want to risk loosing the DVDs so I set out to copy them. Unfortunately, files such as Autorun (yes it's a windoze program...for homeschool kids) do not copy over (ideal iso format). I've tried dd, ddrescue and brasero to no avail.

Does anyone have anything that they can think of that I can use? Without the install programs, the DVD becomes useless except for some of the videos.

I'm on focal.

Thank you for anything.

Comment: What makes you say the autorun and other files don't copy? ddrescue does a bit-for-bit copy of the disk. How are you doing it? I'd do `sudo ddrescue -d -D --force /dev/cdrom ./imagefile.img` or similar.

Comment: I just tried it and I get the same thing. I see most of the files but I don't see files such as the inf and exe files. One new observation is that in its place is a zip file. Upon opening that, I see several files that I think are to go with an installation in the event you're on a MAC. Either way...no joy.

Comment: I just solved the error. I was looking at the iso file via mounting it on ubuntu. For some reason, Ubuntu (or the mounting software Disk Image Mounter) blocks the autorun on the iso from showing and displays files in a zip folder. It shows correctly when it is mounted on a windows machine. Really odd. I'll try and mark this as solved and hope that it helps solve any similar issues someone is having.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some searching, I found that the files are being correctly written to the disk. The problem is in either how the image (iso) is mounted or how Ubuntu deals with displaying the files in the iso. I would assume it is the mounter (Disk Image Mounter).

All of this took a considerable amount of time. I hope this will help someone else to not spend such time when they come through a similar issue.